# Reverse shell from backdoor - exposing attacker?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, tor, backdoor, reverse-shell

If an attacker successfully installed a backdoor that connects to his computer via a reverse shell, how can the attacker hide his IP address?

I'd guess he can't use Tor or a VPN, because packet forwarding would be quite impossible (is that correct?). Maybe he can use a different bought or hacked server as a proxy? How would he achieve that?

How can the attacker stay anonymous?

Comment: @schroeder I have looked at the other posts but those don't answer my question. My questions is specifically about packet forwarding from a reverse shell, not just "hacking" in general. Therefore, can you please open this question again?

Comment: Those posts are about the traffic. Not about hacking. Those answers directly answer your question.

Comment: @Hordeon12 Perhaps if you have a scenario with packet forwarding from a reverse shell that is different from what has been covered in the other answers, you could provide more details of the scenario, e.g., architecture, tools, etc.?

Comment: You could expand your question to include such details, even explaining how it is different from previous question scenarios?